# Python: AttributeError

Tags: python

When I run my script I get this error:

> File "test_cm.py", line 34, in
>
> labels = labels_img.get_data() AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_data'

```
from dipy.tracking.eudx import EuDX
from dipy.reconst import peaks, shm
from dipy.tracking import utils
from dipy.data import read_stanford_labels
from dipy.io.gradients import read_bvals_bvecs

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nibabel as nib

source="prova11/"
path=source

print('loading data')
bvals,bvecs=read_bvals_bvecs(source+"bvals",source+"bvecs")
bvals[bvals < 10] = 0
img = nib.load(source+"segment-TO-b0.nii")
data = img.get_data()
affine=img.affine 
labels_img = read_stanford_labels()
labels = labels_img.get_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

`read_stanford_labels()` returns a tuple, and tuples don't have a `get_data()` method which is why the error says `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_data'`.

You should go over your `read_stanford_labels` function and see why it returns a tuple, which isn't what you expected.

**Edit:** By going over the [documentation/example](http://nipy.org/dipy/examples_built/introduction_to_basic_tracking.html) your code should be
`hardi_img, gtab, labels_img = read_stanford_labels()` instead of
`labels_img = read_stanford_labels()`.

Alternatively, if you don't need the first 2 values, you can use
`labels_img = read_stanford_labels()[-1]` or
`*_, labels_img = read_stanford_labels()`.